# How can I access initialParams on functional components React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass some props to Stack.screen component but I can't find a way to access them on functional component

### App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          initialParams={{ user: { user }, setUser: { setUser } }}
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Login' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen user={user} name="Home" component={Dashboard} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

### LoginScreen.js

Here I'm trying to set token to User with setUser hook but I don't know how to take that prop.

```
function LoginScreen({ navigation, user, setUser }) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleEmailChange = (email) => {
        setEmail(email);
    }
    const handlePasswordChange = (password) => {
        setPassword(password);
    }
    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://mytodoappbackend.herokuapp.com/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                })
            })
            // navigation.navigate('Home', { name: 'Jane' })
            const responseJson = await response.json();
            if (responseJson.token) {
                setUser(responseJson.token);
                navigation.navigate('Home', { name: 'Jane' })
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Hata', 'Kullanıcı adı veya şifre hatalı');
            }
            console.log(responseJson);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    return (
       ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. When I console.log it I get undefined even tho I set it a default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `initialParams` prop of the `StackNavigator`, or by any other navigator in `react-native-navigation`, can be accessed from the `route` prop that is passed by the navgigator to any component that is a `Screen`.

Hence, you can not destructure them directly from `props`. You need to access them via the `route` as follows.

```js
function LoginScreen({ navigation, route }) {
    console.log(route.params)
}
```

Or if you have many route params, then you can still use destructuring as follows.

```js
function LoginScreen({ navigation, route }) {
    const {user, setUser} = route.params
}
```

**Edit:** By the way, you should not pass functions as route params, but this is a different problem…